# AJAX->PHP Sessions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I am using `AJAX` in a hybrid app to authenticate a user and also start a **php session.**

The app has public sections and a user account section. I wanted that when someone logs in they can go to the public sections and return to the user sections without being logged out.

So I wrote an `AJAX request` that is triggered when a user clicks the user section icon to check for sessions. If there is one then the js must load the user home page. If there is none the js must load the login page.

However when the user logs in and tries to return to the user home page the session checking script says the server says there is no session variable set. Below is the code.... First the login then the session checking code.

**login.php**

```
<?php
    require("session.php");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        require("dbconnect.php");
        $inv = sanity($_POST['inv']);
        $acc = sanity($_POST['acc']);
        $pass = sanity($_POST['pass']);

        $query = "SELECT loginid FROM login WHERE institution_id = '$inv' AND username = $acc AND password = '$pass'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {   
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESION['id'] = $row['loginid'];
            echo "1";
        }
        else 
            echo "0";
    }

    function sanity($data)
    {
        $var = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $var = trim($var);
        return $var;
    }
?>
```

**confirm.php**

```
<?php
require("session.php");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
   {   
       if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
           echo "1";
       else
           echo "0";
   }
?>
```

the confirm script is returning zero though the login script returns 1

note that the session.php file does exist

Comment: Did you use session_start(); ?

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Why do you require the session.php file, if it does not exist? And like @VitorLuizdaSilva said - check if you actually used `session_start()` before accessing the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: It is noted kind of confusingly but is says "note that the `session.php` file **does** exist"

Comment: Warning: Your `sanity()` function is not going to protect you against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The session.php file exists and the session is started when one logs in. However when you make an AJAX request to check if $_SESSION['id'] is set. It returns 0 meaning that it is not.

Comment: Injection attack warning noted.